# Record update timestamp not being updated with DynamoDB Enhanced Client

Tags: amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-enhanced-client

My Kotlin Spring Boot application is using the DynamoDB enhanced client to persist a record - the object has a `createdAt` and `updatedAt` field which I'm attempting to get DynamoDB to set automatically as appropriate whenever the record is created/modified, by annotating both timestamp fields with `@get:DynamoDbAutoGeneratedTimestampAttribute`.

While the fields do get set on create, when the update of the record does trigger, the `updatedAt` field is never modified to reflect the latest timestamp, as it should have with the update behavior set to `WRITE_ALWAYS`. What am I missing here?

```
@DynamoDbBean
data class Record(
    @get:DynamoDbPartitionKey
    var uuid: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
    @get:DynamoDbUpdateBehavior(UpdateBehavior.WRITE_IF_NOT_EXISTS)
    @get:DynamoDbAutoGeneratedTimestampAttribute
    var createdAt: Instant? = null,
    @get:DynamoDbUpdateBehavior(UpdateBehavior.WRITE_ALWAYS)
    @get:DynamoDbAutoGeneratedTimestampAttribute
    var updatedAt: Instant? = createdAt
)

@Bean
fun dynamoDbEnhancedClient(): DynamoDbEnhancedClient =
    DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder()
        .dynamoDbClient(dynamoDbClient())
        .extensions(AutoGeneratedTimestampRecordExtension.create())
        .build()
```

Comment: The AWS SDK for Kotlin does not support the Enhanced client at this point in time.To use Amazon DynamoDB and the Kotlin SDK, you need to use aws.sdk.kotlin.services.dynamodb.DynamoDbClient.  You are using the AWS SDK for Java V2 and implementing the logic in the Kotlin programming language.

Comment: @smac2020 Thanks for responding! My understanding was that the Java SDK was interoperable with Kotlin, but it's good to know that it isn't! Would you happen to know why the annotation appears to work on create, but not update?

Comment: Also, if I were to switch to the Kotlin SDK, would I be able to set autogenerated timestamp fields as well?

Comment: I never meant to say you cannot use Kotlin programming language with Java SDK. All I meant was you do not get the coroutine benefits you get with Kotlin SDK.